# Windows right click menu permanently showing

Tags: windows-10, dell-inspiron, context-menu

Whenever I right click and "refresh" or "copy" or "paste" etc., there remains an artifact on the screen. And it remains over everything (including a fullscreen youtube video). Please look at the image below:

[image: dell laptop]

The only way to get rid of it is by locking and logging back in or restarting. Can someone please tell me whether this is a windows bug or something else and how I can fix it?

Comment: Maybe it is because of your background. That would drive me nuts